# Syndaemon Crashes or Locks up

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, macbook, settings

I am trying to use syndaemon -i1 to disable my touchpad while typing.

After a few key strokes, the touchpad will be permenantly disabled (only fixed by a reboot) and will not be re-enabled.

I am using a 2009 Macbook with Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using touchpad-indicator. It uses syndaemon. Be sure to set the prefs for your desires.

In terminal, type the following three commands. Then use the dash to start it.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator